# Building complex Javascript on top of but apart from Drupal

Tags: javascript

Does anyone have any thoughts on developing significant Javascript functionality on top of but separately to a Drupal site?

I have started working on an old Drupal site (dealing with written, news articles) and I have a few reasons for wanting to split off some development, primarily front-end features, into a different code base:

- Accepting contributions from other developers (e.g. in an open-source fashion) may be easier and safer to manage if the front-end alone is being committed to.
- The Drupal site is complicated and bloated. We need to push on with development, ideally collaboratively, but the Drupal site doesn't feel like the most modern or productive code base to work on.
- I think it may be an interesting way to transition from Drupal by building the front-end exoskeleton over it.

I don't mean this to sound negative towards Drupal and I'm sure the techniques I'm looking for will benefit Drupal loyalists too.

**What do I imagine?**

Perhaps the front end-code base, open to public contributions, would include a bunch of javascript (perhaps even a framework app, e.g. angular) and stylesheets.

Ideally this would work within a continuous integration framework where commits to the front-end were tested in an environment containing the latest Drupal production code.

I'm looking for advice and experience. My questions are:

- Is this feasible? Is it being done by any notable, ideally open-source teams? Other thoughts?
- What features do you think this would work with and which not?
- What technology and patterns should I consider, both on the front-end and on Drupal.

Comment: Though an interesting question I fear this will draw "too broad" close votes - there's a significant amount of ground to cover. I have no clue how you'd do it, but if you were able to break this down into more bite-sized chunks and ask them as separate questions, I think everyone would benefit more

Comment: Yes, ok. I'll do that asap.